# JavaScript getter running during inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, getter, prototypal-inheritance

I am playing around with using JavaScript getters and inheritance, and I ran into this interesting behavior. The comments at the end of the lines are the order in which the statements are printing.

```js
function createFruit(size) {
   return {
      get size() {
         console.log('getting size'); // 2, 4
         return size;
      },
   };
}

function createApple(color) {
   let apple = {
      get color() {
         return color;
      },
   };

   return Object.assign(Object.create(apple), createFruit(2));
}


let small = createFruit(1);
console.log('calling getSize fruit'); // 1
console.log(small.size); // 3

let green = createApple('green');
console.log(green.color); // 5
console.log('calling getSize apple'); // 6
console.log(green.size); // 7
```

**Output:**

```
calling getSize fruit
getting size
1
getting size
green
calling getSize apple
2
```

The parts are confused about are the order that four, six, and seven print. I was under the understanding that getters in JavaScript are lazy, meaning they are only called when needed. I don't need to get the size of green until the final line, but the getter is being called when the apple is being constructed. Why is this happening? And how can I rewrite my code to avoid this behavior?

As a side note, please let me know if the general pattern I'm using is a bad way to do this.

Comment: During creation you're using assign, which will loop over the properties and assign them. Have a look at the polyfill of assign: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Oh okay The behavior makes sense then. Would it be best to use .getSize() instead of get size() then? Seems like I would have to introduce a lot more code to enable using the size getter, then.

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking, do you mean just have a method called `getSize` as opposed to using a getter?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: To what end? Seems like it wouldn't really make any difference.

Comment: In order to only call the getter when needed. I'm trying to use this pattern for a more complicated problem, so I wrote the small example to try to figure out what's going on. Also, feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it, seeing as you answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) does not copy property attributes like getter functions, it uses them to evaluate the property value and copy *that* onto the target. So during the `createApple` call, the getter is invoked and a non-getter `size` property is created on the `apple` object.

> How can I rewrite my code to avoid this behavior?

Don't use `Object.assign` with objects that contain accessory properties as source arguments. You can write

```
function createApple(color) {
  return Object.defineProperties(createFruit(2), {
    color: {
      get() {
        return color;
      }
    }
  });
}
```